# How to pass activity's function to compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to pass a activity's function with parameter to a compose function?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                Main(
                    activityFunWithParam = activityFunWithParam // not work
                )
            }
        }
    }

    fun activityFunWithParam(param: Param) {
        ...
    }
}

@Composable
fun Main(
    activityFunWithPara: (Param) -> Unit
) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass it as a method reference

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Main(activityFunWithParam = ::activityFunWithParam)
        }
    }

    fun activityFunWithParam(param: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(this, param.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

@Composable
fun Main(
        activityFunWithParam: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    activityFunWithParam(5)
    Text(text = "Test")
}
```

In your example, method name itself is not a function. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type